# live write operations on solr cloud

Tags: mongodb, solr, solrcloud

We implemented solr cloud on 3 replicas and three shards. We are importing data from Mongo and indexing it to solr. While adding data to solr we found two solutions.

1. Add live data as user registered and create profile it will get indexed in solr.
2. Using cron pull data from mongo and index to solr.

Solution 2 is complex as we need to mentain failure status and all.

If we select solution 1 what will be actual problem in production environment? If any benchmark available ?

High availability and performance is main concerns